# Extra increment within for loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Is the following code safe and defined in the standard? Will 'i' be incremented by 2 if 'condition' is true?

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    do_something;
    if (condition)
        i++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. And it is common to write such things. `for` is mostly a syntactic sugar for a `while` loop.

Comment: yes,undoubtdly...it is the general flow of the program,no special case

Comment: IMO, not because it is allowed in the standard and that it works makes it safe (and/or easy to maintain in the long run).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. There is nothing wrong with it - syntactically. You can even do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (;;) {
    if (i >= 100) {

      break;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

This code is equivalent to

```
int i = 0;
while(true) {
    if (i >= 100) {
        break;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

And furthermore - you can place practically any valid code into the for statement. E.g.

```
for (do_something_begin(); some_condition(); do_something_end()) {
     CODE;
}
```

and what compiler does with this code is something like this:

```
do_something_begin()
while (some_condition()) {
    CODE;
    do_something_end();
}
```

Comment: And yes - I am aware of the fact, that it is not exactly the same as what compiler does (variable scope of do_something_begin() is just wrong) but for educational reasons I find it better to keep it like this.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in some other languages it is illegal to modify the loop counter within the loop, and that outside the loop the loop counter's value is undefined (regardless of the variable scope). C/C++ isn't like this. Don't let the fact it is illegal in other languages put you off doing it in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

If I starts at 0 and the condition is true then i=1, then when the loop iterates again i will be increased by 1 to 2 so yes.

Answer (score 0):

You just wrote

```
size_t i = 0;

while (i < 100) {
    do_something;
    if (condition)
        i++;
    i++;
}
```

This is perfectly legal. If I were you I would add a comment saying "Skip the next one".